# Is it the right way to download emulators to solve the errors encountered in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, crashlytics

I am getting the following error in my android mobile app. I need to test to see if my solution works. For this, I tried to download the Galaxy A73 emulator from the official site of Samsung, but it constantly asks me for verification. In addition, we can use the emulator you downloaded from there for a very short time.

My question is: Is the way I've tried to solve this type of device-specific error correct? Is it the correct solution to try to download the emulator of that device and open the app on the emulator? Or is there a more practical solution to this?

[image]

Comment: In the normal Android Studio emulator everything works?

Comment: In my experience when trying to recreate a problem that only occurs on a certain type of real device it's best to get a real device since it's very possible that it can't be recreated on the emulator of that device.

Comment: I can confirm that. When developing apps you should have at least 10 old used phones to test the app.

Comment: When I start the application with android studio, there is no problem. Wouldn't it be very difficult to physically obtain each device? Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: you don't have to get every device, but Samsung's version of Android is substantially different from Google's.  Any medium-grade Samsung would be really valuable to test on.